# Show only the latest record using laravel query builder

Tags: laravel

I have two tables a payments table and a tenants table. Each payments table can have many payments for a single tenant (one to many relationship)

```
Payments 
id    tenant_id   amount 
1     1                  5000    
2     1                  6000
3     2                  7000    
4     2                  8000

tenants 
id    name         email
1     peter         peter@info.com
2     grace         grace@info.com
```

When i run the following in my controller

```
public function getPaymentsList(Request $request)
    {
       $payments = DB::table("payments")
       ->join('tenants','tenants.id','=','tenant_id')
       ->select('payments.id','payments.tenant_id','tenants.name','payments.rent_to')
       ->groupBy('tenant_id')->get()
;      
      
 return  response()->json($payments);
    }
   
}
```

I get json content of the oldest record in the payments table not the latest record.

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"tenant_id": 1,
"name": "peter",
"amount": "5000"
},
{
"id": 3,
"tenant_id": 2,
"name": "grace",
"amount": "7000"
},
]

The output i want is

[
{
"id": 2,
"tenant_id": 1,
"name": "peter",
"amount": "6000"
},
{
"id": 4,
"tenant_id": 2,
"name": "grace",
"amount": "8000"
},
]
```

How to improve the above query so that it can display the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like:

```
public function getPaymentsList(Request $request)
{
   $payments = DB::table("payments")
   ->join('tenants','tenants.id','=','tenant_id')
   ->select('payments.id','payments.tenant_id','tenants.name','payments.rent_to')
   ->groupBy('tenant_id')->latest()->first()
;      
      
 return  response()->json($payments);
    }
   
}
```

check the larvel [documents](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) for useing `latest()->first()`